# Forecast Entry - Can this mean the process of entering data into a computer form?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Our company's customers are forecasters. Some of them (non-native English speakers) use the term **Forecast Entry** to describe the process of sitting in front of the computer and entering a weather forecast into a form, populating the items one by one.

To me, this doesn't sound like a correct usage of the word *entry*. The word entry in this context sounds to me like *forecast item* or *forecast record*, which is wrong, of course.

Can the phrase *Forecast Entry* mean the process of populating a form, or can you suggest a better term?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usage is absolutely fine - you're right that *entry* can mean the same as *record* or *item*, but it can also mean *the process of entering* (e.g. information into a system), as in the phrase [*data entry*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/data-entry).

For example, see [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/entry):

> 4a : the act of making or entering a record